# solr returns duplicate records when paginating using edismax

Tags: solr, pagination

I am using solr 3.5 and facing a weird behavior when paginating. Some identical records / documents are being returned by solr when paginating; Example, I get a document in page one and I am getting the same document in the third page. After troubleshooting I realized that Solr behaves like this when using `edismax` query parser. Pagination works well when using the default parser. Any ideas why??

below are the decoded queries for each paginated page

page 1

```
spellcheck=true&spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=false&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.count=1&spellcheck.collate=true&q=coffee AND countryId:1&defType=edismax&start=0&rows=10&fl=outletId,outletPhone1,outletPhone2,outletPhone3,outletUrl,outletGpsLatitude,outletGpsLongitude,outletAddress,outletPrimaryName,outletSecondaryName,brateCount,brateit_review,views,outletAvarageRating,outletRatingId,outletRatingValue,poBox,locatedInOutletId,locatedInOutletPrimaryName,locatedInOutletSecondaryName,locatedInName,floor,addressPlaceId,addressPlaceName_en,streetId,streetName_en,areaId,areaName_en,cityId,cityName_en,countryId,countryCode,countryName_en,plsId,plsName_en,categoryId,categoryName_en,ratingId,ratingName_en,primaryCategoryId,primaryCategoryName_en,primaryIndustryId,primaryIndustryName_en&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.sort=count&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=facetCityName_en&facet.field=facetPoolCategory_en&facet.field=facetAreaName_en&sort=score desc, outletAvarageRating desc,brateCount desc,views desc,random_1347951132109 desc
```

page 2

```
spellcheck=true&spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=false&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.count=1&spellcheck.collate=true&q=coffee AND countryId:1&defType=edismax&start=10&rows=10&fl=outletId,outletPhone1,outletPhone2,outletPhone3,outletUrl,outletGpsLatitude,outletGpsLongitude,outletAddress,outletPrimaryName,outletSecondaryName,brateCount,brateit_review,views,outletAvarageRating,outletRatingId,outletRatingValue,poBox,locatedInOutletId,locatedInOutletPrimaryName,locatedInOutletSecondaryName,locatedInName,floor,addressPlaceId,addressPlaceName_en,streetId,streetName_en,areaId,areaName_en,cityId,cityName_en,countryId,countryCode,countryName_en,plsId,plsName_en,categoryId,categoryName_en,ratingId,ratingName_en,primaryCategoryId,primaryCategoryName_en,primaryIndustryId,primaryIndustryName_en&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.sort=count&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=facetCityName_en&facet.field=facetPoolCategory_en&facet.field=facetAreaName_en&sort=score desc, outletAvarageRating desc,brateCount desc,views desc,random_1347951219828 desc
```

page 3

```
spellcheck=true&spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=false&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.count=1&spellcheck.collate=true&q=coffee AND countryId:1&defType=edismax&start=20&rows=10&fl=outletId,outletPhone1,outletPhone2,outletPhone3,outletUrl,outletGpsLatitude,outletGpsLongitude,outletAddress,outletPrimaryName,outletSecondaryName,brateCount,brateit_review,views,outletAvarageRating,outletRatingId,outletRatingValue,poBox,locatedInOutletId,locatedInOutletPrimaryName,locatedInOutletSecondaryName,locatedInName,floor,addressPlaceId,addressPlaceName_en,streetId,streetName_en,areaId,areaName_en,cityId,cityName_en,countryId,countryCode,countryName_en,plsId,plsName_en,categoryId,categoryName_en,ratingId,ratingName_en,primaryCategoryId,primaryCategoryName_en,primaryIndustryId,primaryIndustryName_en&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.sort=count&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=facetCityName_en&facet.field=facetPoolCategory_en&facet.field=facetAreaName_en&sort=score desc, outletAvarageRating desc,brateCount desc,views desc,random_1347951286359 desc
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i added my solr query requests above. the schema is a bit big though; should i post it as well?

Comment: Could you show us what is the response that you get and what you would expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with my sorting implementation. i was sorting by random field on each page causing the document to keep shifting between pages.

```
String randomField = random_"+ (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: I experience exactly the same behavior except I didn't specify any order. The same problem persists if I add an order to a specific field. Still not sure how to resolve this issue. Among 510k keys, 340k are unique ..